# reading blob data from sqlite database -> jpa (hibernate)

Tags: hibernate, sqlite, blob

Hy!

I want to read blob data from a sqlite database but I always get this error message

```
08.05.2012 15:06:28 org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
WARN: SQL Error: 0, SQLState: null
08.05.2012 15:06:28 org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: not implemented by SQLite JDBC driver
```

I am using JSF,Spring,JPA(hibernate).

Sqlite Table Structure

```
CREATE TABLE LOGO ('logo_id' INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, 'logo_data' BLOB)
```

The code for reading one line:

```
public void loadLogo() {
    try {
        Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery("SELECT * FROM logo");
        Vector v = (Vector) query.getSingleResult();
        byte[] blobData = (byte[]) v.elementAt(1);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Sqlite Dialect:

```
public class SQLiteDialect extends Dialect implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public SQLiteDialect() {
    registerColumnType(Types.BIT, "integer");
    registerColumnType(Types.TINYINT, "tinyint");
    registerColumnType(Types.SMALLINT, "smallint");
    registerColumnType(Types.INTEGER, "integer");
    registerColumnType(Types.BIGINT, "bigint");
    registerColumnType(Types.FLOAT, "float");
    registerColumnType(Types.REAL, "real");
    registerColumnType(Types.DOUBLE, "double");
    registerColumnType(Types.NUMERIC, "numeric");
    registerColumnType(Types.DECIMAL, "decimal");
    registerColumnType(Types.CHAR, "char");
    registerColumnType(Types.VARCHAR, "varchar");
    registerColumnType(Types.LONGVARCHAR, "longvarchar");
    registerColumnType(Types.DATE, "date");
    registerColumnType(Types.TIME, "time");
    registerColumnType(Types.TIMESTAMP, "timestamp");
    registerColumnType(Types.BINARY, "blob");
    registerColumnType(Types.VARBINARY, "blob");
    registerColumnType(Types.LONGVARBINARY, "blob");
    registerColumnType(Types.NULL, "null");
    registerColumnType(Types.BLOB, "blob");
    registerColumnType(Types.CLOB, "clob");
    registerColumnType(Types.BOOLEAN, "integer");

    registerFunction("concat", new VarArgsSQLFunction(
            StandardBasicTypes.STRING, "", "||", ""));
    registerFunction("mod", new SQLFunctionTemplate(
            StandardBasicTypes.INTEGER, "?1 % ?2"));
    registerFunction("substr", new StandardSQLFunction("substr",
            StandardBasicTypes.STRING));
    registerFunction("substring", new StandardSQLFunction("substr",
            StandardBasicTypes.STRING));
}

public boolean supportsIdentityColumns() {
    return true;
}

/*
 * public boolean supportsInsertSelectIdentity() { return true; // As
 * specify in NHibernate dialect }
 */

public boolean hasDataTypeInIdentityColumn() {
    return false; // As specify in NHibernate dialect
}

/*
 * public String appendIdentitySelectToInsert(String insertString) { return
 * new StringBuffer(insertString.length()+30). // As specify in NHibernate
 * dialect append(insertString).
 * append("; ").append(getIdentitySelectString()). toString(); }
 */

public String getIdentityColumnString() {
    // return "integer primary key autoincrement";
    return "integer";
}

public String getIdentitySelectString() {
    return "select last_insert_rowid()";
}

public boolean supportsLimit() {
    return true;
}

protected String getLimitString(String query, boolean hasOffset) {
    return new StringBuffer(query.length() + 20).append(query)
            .append(hasOffset ? " limit ? offset ?" : " limit ?")
            .toString();
}

public boolean supportsTemporaryTables() {
    return true;
}

public String getCreateTemporaryTableString() {
    return "create temporary table if not exists";
}

public boolean dropTemporaryTableAfterUse() {
    return false;
}

public boolean supportsCurrentTimestampSelection() {
    return true;
}

public boolean isCurrentTimestampSelectStringCallable() {
    return false;
}

public String getCurrentTimestampSelectString() {
    return "select current_timestamp";
}

public boolean supportsUnionAll() {
    return true;
}

public boolean hasAlterTable() {
    return false; // As specify in NHibernate dialect
}

public boolean dropConstraints() {
    return false;
}

public String getAddColumnString() {
    return "add column";
}

public String getForUpdateString() {
    return "";
}

public boolean supportsOuterJoinForUpdate() {
    return false;
}

public String getDropForeignKeyString() {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException(
            "No drop foreign key syntax supported by SQLiteDialect");
}

public String getAddForeignKeyConstraintString(String constraintName,
        String[] foreignKey, String referencedTable, String[] primaryKey,
        boolean referencesPrimaryKey) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException(
            "No add foreign key syntax supported by SQLiteDialect");
}

public String getAddPrimaryKeyConstraintString(String constraintName) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException(
            "No add primary key syntax supported by SQLiteDialect");
}

public boolean supportsIfExistsBeforeTableName() {
    return true;
}

public boolean supportsCascadeDelete() {
    return false;
}
```

}

Please help me!

Thanks

Comment: "not implemented by SQLite JDBC driver" is pretty clear: you *cannot* read blobs using this driver, unless you implement the support yourself.

Comment: But there are no problems with writing blob data onto the database!  And how is this done?? Is there another SQLite JDBC driver implementation or an example how to implement such an support?!

Answer (score 0):

The wisdom of Google, e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6090170/cannot-save-image-as-blob-to-sqlite), suggests that while the SQLite JDBC driver does support BLOB support, it doesn't actually provide all of the normal operations. For instance, it implements `setBytes` but not `setBinaryStream`. The usual workaround is just to adapt your way of accessing the data.

Since you are not getting a stack trace, it is unclear if this is your problem; you should try to get Hibernate to give you a stack trace rather than just the Exception message. If your problem is caused by such partial support, you have to either get Hibernate to change its way of accessing Blobs (no idea how, sorry), or go behind Hibernate's back by using a `PreparedStatement` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer. I tried to use the prepared statement this way. First I get the Session whith entity.Manager.unwrawp(Session.class); and than I call the doWork function session.doWork(){execute(Connection con){....} and in the execute function I create the prepared statement with con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM logo); And next I use the ResultSet to get the blob bytes. But now I get the error "ResultSet closed" and the SQLState is still null.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I have a solution. I had to make the sql processing on my own.

I have a static method which reads data from the database (static, because @Inject can not be used in Servlet)

```
public static byte[] loadLogo() {
    byte[] ar = null;
    Connection con;
    Statement stmt;
    String driver = "org.sqlite.JDBC";
    String url = "jdbc:sqlite:X:\\Projekte\\Bauer - Rainstar\\Entwickler\\database\\rainstar_ds.sqlite";
    try {
        Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
        con.setAutoCommit(false);

        stmt = con.createStatement();

        ResultSet set = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM logo");
        set.next();
        ar = set.getBytes("logo_data");

        con.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return ar;
}
```

And I implemented a HttpServlet:

```
@WebServlet("/images/*")
public class ImageServlet extends HttpServlet {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    OutputStream os = resp.getOutputStream();
    byte[] temp = LogoServiceImpl.loadLogo();
    os.write(temp);
}
```

}

On the page I only need to specify the following, to show my pic on the page.

```
<img src="images/xx" />
```

And I also had to add these lines to the web.xml file

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Image Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>at.beko.rainstar2.ui.controller.ImageServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Image Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/images/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I stored my Image File this way.

```
@Override
public void saveLogo(UploadedFile file) {
    try {
        Query query = entityManager
                .createNativeQuery("INSERT INTO 'logo' VALUES (?,?)");
        query.setParameter(1, "2");
        query.setParameter(2, getBytesFromFile(file));
        query.executeUpdate();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private byte[] getBytesFromFile(UploadedFile file) throws IOException {
    InputStream is = file.getInputstream();

    long length = file.getSize();
    if (length > Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
        // File is too large
    }

    byte[] bytes = new byte[(int) length];

    int offset = 0;
    int numRead = 0;
    int realLength = bytes.length;
    while (offset < realLength
            && (numRead = is.read(bytes, offset, realLength - offset)) >= 0) {
        offset += numRead;
    }

    if (offset < realLength) {
        throw new IOException("Could not completely read file "
                + file.getFileName());
    }

    is.close();
    return bytes;
}
```

This is my beforehand solution!! So do not mind the hardcoded parts ^^