# Error java.sql.SQLException: not implemented by SQLite JDBC driver when Retrieving Blob (Image) from Database

Tags: java, database, swing, sqlite, jdbc

When I try to retrieve an image(Blob) file from Sqlite database it gives me these error . I have used many jars , such as rs2xml , sqlitejdbc-v056 , sqlite-jdbc-3.8.11 and even all the old versions of it . 
here is the stacktrace .

```
java.sql.SQLException: not implemented by SQLite JDBC driver
at org.sqlite.Unused.unused(Unused.java:31)
at org.sqlite.Unused.getBlob(Unused.java:86)
at Show$2.actionPerformed(Show.java:75)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$300(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Here is my code

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.sql.Blob;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class Show extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JTextField id;
    BufferedImage bufImg = null;
    JLabel img = null;
    InputStream in = null;
    ImageIcon imgs = null;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Show frame = new Show();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    Connection con = null;

    public Show() {
        con = dB.Connect();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 588, 432);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        id = new JTextField();
        id.setBounds(158, 23, 86, 20);
        contentPane.add(id);
        id.setColumns(10);

        JButton show = new JButton("New button");
        show.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                try {
                    String q = "select image from showme where id='" + id.getText() + "'";
                    PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(q);
                    ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
                    try {
                        while (rs.next()) {
                            // problems might be occurring in here
                            Blob blob = rs.getBlob(2);
                            ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(blob.getBytes(2, (int) blob.length()));
                            img.setIcon(icon);
                        }
                    } catch (SQLException x) {
                        x.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Done");

                    // in.close();
                    rs.close();
                    ps.close();

                } catch (Exception c) {
                    c.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        show.setBounds(302, 22, 89, 23);
        contentPane.add(show);

        img = new JLabel("");
        img.setBounds(151, 99, 325, 284);
        contentPane.add(img);
    }
}
```

Edit:
I Tried Using Bytearray . Though its not showing me any error but it is not giving me any out put . ! here is the modified portion

```
   try {
        String q = "select image from showme where id='"+id.getText()+"'";
        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(q);
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();       
         if(rs.next()) {
            byte[] imgss = rs.getBytes("image");
            //Resize The ImageIcon
            ImageIcon mage = new ImageIcon(imgss);
            Image im = mage.getImage();
            Image myImg = im.getScaledInstance(imgss.length, imgss.length,imgss.length);
            ImageIcon newImage = new ImageIcon(myImg);
            img.setIcon(newImage);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Done");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Without using getBlob method how can i retrieve Blob file ?

Comment: you may get your image as byte array resultset .getBytes("image");

Comment: possible this link may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6090170/cannot-save-image-as-blob-to-sqlite

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
byte[] byteArr = rs.getBytes("image");
```

Comment: i have used bytearray . . Though it gives me no error . But it is not setting the image to Jlabel ! dont know why !

Answer (score 0):

Use `getBinaryStream()` instead. Something like the following:

```
ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();     
InputStream in = rs.getBinaryStream("image");
ByteArrayOutpuStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int bytesRead = in.read(buffer);
while (bytesRead > -1)
{
  out.write(buffer, bytesRead)
  bytesRead = in.read(buffer);
}
byte[] picture = out.toByteArray();
in.close();
```

You will of course need to add exception handling to the above.

If you are using the Apache Commons IO library you can simplify that using `IOUtils.toByteArray()`

```
ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();     
InputStream in = rs.getBinaryStream("image");
byte[] picture = IOUtils.toByteArray(in);
```

Comment: The problem is it is not showing me the picture in JLabel . Is there some other kind of problem ?

Comment: @CodeHead: `new ByteArrayOutputStream();` is perfectly fine. Did you verify that your byte array does contain the correct data? So that we know if this is a problem with _retrieving_ or _displaying_ the image

Comment: I have verified that the datas in my database are not corrupted and correct .

Comment: I don't mean the data _in_ the database, I mean the content of the byte array after you retrieved the data (e.g. using a debugger)

Comment: Sorry for asking a lame question . I am pretty nOob . Can you tell how can i verify that ?

Answer (score 0):

**ERROR:**

```
java.sql.SQLException: not implemented by SQLite JDBC driver
at org.sqlite.Unused.unused(Unused.java:31)
at org.sqlite.Unused.getBlob(Unused.java:86)
```

**AT:**

```
//problems might be occurring in here 
Blob blob=rs.getBlob(2);
```

**TRY:**

```
Byte blob=rs.getByte(2);
```