# No output in JLabel when trying to retrieve blob image from JLabel

Tags: java, database, swing, sqlite, blob

I am trying to retrieve a Blob(Image) file from database and want to show it in a JLabel . But it doesnt show up in JLabel . Why ? one More query if there any to know if my Byte array Contains valid data ? Here is my code

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.ImageObserver;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class Show extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JTextField id;
    //BufferedImage bufImg = null;
    JLabel img=null;
    //   InputStream in=null;
    ImageIcon imgs=null;
    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Show frame = new Show();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    Connection con=null;
    public Show() {
        con=dB.Connect();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 664, 499);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        id = new JTextField();
        id.setBounds(158, 23, 86, 20);
        contentPane.add(id);
        id.setColumns(10);

        JButton show = new JButton("New button");
        show.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                try{

                    String q="select * from showme where id='"+id.getText()+"'";
                    PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement(q);
                    ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery(); 

                    InputStream in = rs.getBinaryStream("image");

                    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    while(rs.next()){
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                    int bytesRead = in.read(buffer);
                    while (bytesRead > -1)
                    {
                      out.write(buffer);
                      bytesRead = in.read(buffer);
                    }
                    byte[] picture = out.toByteArray();
                    ImageIcon mage = new ImageIcon(picture);
                    Image im = mage.getImage();
                    ImageIcon newImage = new ImageIcon(im);
                    //Image myImg = im.getScaledInstance(img.getWidth(),img.getWidth(),ImageObserver.WIDTH);
                    //ImageIcon newImage = new ImageIcon(myImg);
                    img.setIcon(newImage);
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Done");

                    /*//I Also used this method . Still No Result in Jlabel 
                     while(rs.next()){
                        byte[] imgss = rs.getBytes("image");
                        //Resize The ImageIcon
                        ImageIcon mage = new ImageIcon(imgss);
                        Image im = mage.getImage();
                        //Image myImg = im.getScaledInstance(imgss.length, imgss.length,imgss.length);
                        //ImageIcon newImage = new ImageIcon(im);
                        img.setIcon(new ImageIcon(im));
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Done");
                     }
                        */

                    in.close();
                    rs.close();
                    ps.close();
                    }
                    }catch(Exception c)
                    {
                        c.printStackTrace();
                    }
            }
        });
        show.setBounds(302, 22, 89, 23);
        contentPane.add(show);

        img = new JLabel("");
        img.setBounds(114, 54, 269, 171);
        contentPane.add(img);
    }

}
```

This is the code for inserting the image

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;

public class ImgC1 {

private JFrame frame;
private JLabel image;
private File images;
DataBufferByte data;
String s;
WritableRaster raster;  
ImageIcon photo;
private static final int IMG_WIDTH = 120;
private static final int IMG_HEIGHT = 120;
/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                ImgC1 window = new ImgC1();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the application.
 */

public ImgC1() {
    initialize();
}

/**
 * Initialize the contents of the frame.
 */
Connection con=null;
private JTextField id;
 public ImageIcon ResizeImage(String imgPath){
     ImageIcon MyImage = new ImageIcon(imgPath);
        Image img = MyImage.getImage();
        Image newImage = img.getScaledInstance(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(),Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
        ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(newImage);
        return image;
 }
 private static BufferedImage resizeImage(BufferedImage originalImage, int type) {
        BufferedImage resizedImage = new BufferedImage(IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT, type);
        Graphics2D g = resizedImage.createGraphics();
        g.drawImage(originalImage, 0, 0, IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT, null);
        g.dispose();

        return resizedImage;
    }
 public Image toImage(BufferedImage bufferedImage) {
        return Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(bufferedImage.getSource());
    }
private void initialize() {

    con=dB.Connect();
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 643, 444);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    JButton browse = new JButton("Browse");
    browse.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

            JFileChooser chooser;
            FileNameExtensionFilter filter;
            chooser = new JFileChooser();
            chooser.setCurrentDirectory(images);
            filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("jpeg, gif and png files", "jpg", "gif", "png");
            chooser.addChoosableFileFilter(filter);

            int i = chooser.showSaveDialog(null);
            if (i == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                images = chooser.getSelectedFile();
                image.setText(images.getAbsolutePath());
                try {
                    BufferedImage originalImage = ImageIO.read(images);
                    int type = originalImage.getType() == 0 ? BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB : originalImage.getType();
                    photo=new ImageIcon();
                    BufferedImage resizeImageJpg = resizeImage(originalImage, type);
                    photo = new ImageIcon(toImage(resizeImageJpg));


                    raster = resizeImageJpg.getRaster();
                    data = (DataBufferByte) raster.getDataBuffer();

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                }


            }
        }

    });
    browse.setBounds(270, 282, 89, 23);
    frame.getContentPane().add(browse);

    JButton save = new JButton("Save");
    save.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            try{
                 PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("insert into showme(id,image) values (?,?)");
                 //InputStream is = new FileInputStream(new File(s));
                 byte[] bt=data.getData();
                 ps.setString(1, id.getText());
                 ps.setBytes(2,bt);
                 ps.executeUpdate();
                 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Data Inserted");
                 ps.close();
            }catch(Exception c)
            {
                c.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    save.setBounds(270, 316, 89, 23);
    frame.getContentPane().add(save);

     image = new JLabel("New label");
    image.setBounds(236, 141, 168, 130);
    frame.getContentPane().add(image);

    id = new JTextField();
    id.setBounds(206, 60, 232, 23);
    frame.getContentPane().add(id);
    id.setColumns(10);
}
```

}

Comment: after `ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();` you missed `rs.next();` directly you can `byte[] buffer = rs.getBytes("image");`

Comment: @Satya - I tried with that . Still no result

Comment: I mean nothing shows in the JLabel

Comment: individually 1. check whether you are getting image from db or not. just save that image in some folder. 2. check label is working or not. add some default image to label from some folder.

Comment: The Second one worked fine , but i am not sure how to do the first one , sorry . I am a noob . Can you give me a hint ?

Comment: see this sample http://www.programcreek.com/2009/02/java-convert-image-to-byte-array-convert-byte-array-to-image/

Comment: When i am trying to save the file in a directory it gives me this error
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: image == null!

Comment: in that link two lines are enough.

Comment: I did what you have told me , But gives me this error --- java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: image == null! – what is the cache ?

Comment: means byte array null?

Comment: Yes ! The Byte array is not getting any data from DB ! I have checked my database . The datas are fine . Then what is causing this problem

Comment: problem with db. did you use `byte=getBlob("image")`

Comment: Yes and it kept me giving SQLEXCEPTION:not implemented by SQLite JDBC driver

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6090170/cannot-save-image-as-blob-to-sqlite

Comment: Yes i checked that earlier , but my issue remain unsolved

Comment: Believe i am stuck with this problem since 2 days , i have watched most of the post related to this topic , tried everything , but couldnt resolve it :(

Comment: while inserting are you using setBytes()? since setBytes() , getBytes() works properly with sqlite.

Comment: I have attached the insertion code in here . Yes I did use setBytes() .